# Add a text in the cursor position in an textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to add text at the end of the cursor's position in VB.NET 
I tried:

```
 TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Insert(TextBox1.SelectionStart, "<br>")
```

It works but the cursor position still moves to the starting position.

Answer (score 7):

Just re-set the `SelectionStart` property after assigning the text:

```
Dim insertText = "<br>"
Dim insertPos As Integer = TextBox1.SelectionStart
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Insert(insertPos, insertText)
TextBox1.SelectionStart = insertPos + insertText.Length
```

Answer (score 5):

Turns out there's a really easy way to do this.

```
TextBox1.SelectedText = "<br>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after your code to move the caret to the end of your textbox value:

```
TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.TextLength
```